# Output random number to file in linux in C

Tags: c, linux, file-io, systems-programming

I'm trying to write a number (randomly generated) to a file using a loop for some number of iterations. I have:

```
while (i++ < number) {
   n = randno();
   write(openFd, (char) n, sizeof(int)); 
}
```

The code compiles and runs. I can print 'n' to the screen, a file has been opened (code not shown), but there does not seem to be any data in the file when I try to open it using `gedit`. I want a file with one very large number of a certain length. Where am I going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

By the way, what is a `true random function`? Thank you.

Comment: how random must your numbers be? Why don't you use a true random function to achieve it?

Comment: You can simply cast a number `n` to a char. Were you sleeping in class?

Comment: Could you check the return status of the `write()` function. On success, it should return the number of bytes written to the file. That would confirm what was written to file.

Comment: This is in C/C++, right? Can you add that detail to your Q so it's more obvious? Also add the appropriate tag(s).

Comment: This should go to SO, imho.

Comment: Sorry, typo. I meant to say you can't. my fingers are freezing from the cold here.


You cannot cast an int to a char and expect to see a string.
Try looking at file with `od` and you'll see what is being written

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for `write()` is:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

Notice the second arg is a **pointer** value, so it is a little bit surprising that passing that a random number there (which is what you have done<sup>1</sup>) does not seg fault.

Anyway, if what you want to do is do is write the number *as text*, you need to put it into a string first:

```
int n = randno();
char buffer[16]; // Will hold any int value + `\0`
sprintf(buffer, "%d", n);
```

You can now use `buffer` with `write`:

```
write(openFd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
```

---

<sup>1. `n` is an int; casting it with `(char)` simply truncates it.  Perhaps you meant `(char*)&n`, which will work to write out the number, but in binary, not text!  I presume that's not what you want since you were examining the file in gedit.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could also use fprintf if you have a FILE*

```
fprintf(fp, "%d",n);
```

Answer (score 1):

By casting n to a char type you have created something that will randomly write the memory pointed to from a number between 0 to 255. Expanding what you are doing, all you would need is.

```
while (i++ < number) {
   int n;
   n = randno();
   write(openFd, &n, sizeof(int)); 
}
```

The & operator will pass a pointer to N instead of the n value...

Answer (score 0):

A true random function is something that output real random numbers that are not computable.

/dev/random on linux as opposed to /dev/urandom.

For your file-write I would use ''fprintf''